# ColdFusion, Trying to parse a tab delimited string

Tags: coldfusion

I have a short test program to extract strings separated by tabs.  The output does not make sense to me. The idea is to find the next tab position, and return the values in between the previous and next tab.

The output of my program below. Where did the "a rob" come from?

```
    fred     ted    rob a rob   alex
```

**program**

```
<cfscript>
   s="fred"&chr(9)&"ted"&chr(9)&"rob"&chr(9)&"alex";

   oldp=0;
   while(oldp<Len(s))
   {
       p=Find(chr(9),s,oldp+1);
       if (p==0)
           break;
       m=Mid(s,oldp+1,p); // oldp is the old tab poit p is the new get string in between
       WriteOutput(m);
       WriteOutput(" ");
       oldp=p;
   }
 </cfscript>
```

Now if I change the program to print out `oldp` after each string the result is:

```
fred => 1 
ted rob a => 6 
rob alex => 10
```

I would expect to see `1,5,9,`. I don't understand why `ted rob` is the second string. I  would expect to see `rob` instead.

Comment: Do not forget to use code tags `{...}` so your code snippets display properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Mid(s,oldp+1,p);
```

To answer your question, that is not how [mid](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7b56.html) works. The third parameter `p` is the number of characters to return, not a position in the string.

```
  mid(s, 6, 3) ; // this would return "Ted"
```

If I can make a suggestion - it is much easier to treat the string as a list, separated by tabs. Then parse it with list functions.

```
<cfscript>
    str = "red"& chr(9) &"ted"& chr(9) &"rob"& chr(9) &"alex";
    for (i = 1; i <= listLen(str, chr(9)); i++) {
        WriteDump( listGetAt(str, i, chr(9)) );
    }
</cfscript>
```

Note, most list functions ignore empty elements. If you wish to preserve them, use [listToArray](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f0f.html).

```
<cfscript>
    str = "red"& chr(9) &"ted"& chr(9) &"rob"& chr(9) &"alex";
    arr = listToArray(str, chr(9), true);
    for (i = 1; i <= arrayLen(arr); i++) {
        WriteDump( arr[i] );
    }
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Hi,Your idear of treating it like a list, much better then mine, thank you for the tip.